# How to get the exact value from an expression string without jeval in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I hava use jeval to get result from an expression string,but I find that sometimes I get the wrong result.So I try to use the BigDecimal,it is Ok,but if my express is more complex like `(0.1+0.2)*10+15/3` How can I encapsulated into a function,do any jar or lib that have this function?
The code is here:

```
 Evaluator eval = new Evaluator();
 String expression="(0.1+0.2)";
 String rest = eval.evaluate(expression);
 System.out.println(new BigDecimal(rest));  //0.30000000000000004
```

Here is my own function:

```
private String getResult(String expression){
  java.math.BigDecimal b = new java.math.BigDecimal("0.1");
  java.math.BigDecimal c = new java.math.BigDecimal("0.2");
  return b.add(c);
 }
```

Comment: You need a pretty basic parser/evaluator, as is taught in university in first or second year. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: See this [Equation Solver](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/equation-solver) code for one way to create a parser / evaluator.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut,using Javascript engine may be an option,but it can not solve the problem with floating-point math.

Comment: There is more than one answer at this link. You may also implement Dijkstra's [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) (typical exercise), or use [Apache JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/), or any other existing package. I strongly suggest you implement it if you have never done this before: not difficult, and quite rewarding as you will be able to reuse the algorithm in many contexts.